# Is there a way to loop part of a video on macOS?

Tags: software-recommendation, video

I'm trying to learn a language from a video. For this I would like to loop part of a video indefinitely, and additionally be able to change the speed of the video while it's playing back. Is there any way to loop part of a video like this on macOS?

The simplest way I can think of is by trimming the video with ffmpeg or QuickTime Player, but that would become quite cumbersome with multiple parts of the video. There's also an online service called Looptube which does that that I've been using (for YouTube videos), but it's quite buggy and doesn't work at all half the time, so I've given up using it.

Comment: How important is it to loop **parts** of the video? Is it easy for you to extract the parts you want to loop, i.e. would it be sufficient for you to be able to loop full videos?

Comment: I'm looking specifically for looping parts of the video, yeah (like 10 seconds of it, for example). I know you can loop full videos in IINA but just don't want to extract all the parts before everything I want to loop

Comment: It was there in an answer, now deleted - VLC can vary speed & set loop points.

Comment: Thanks! Wonder why the answer was deleted, it seems to solve my question

Answer (score 0):

One way is to open it in Quicktime Player, make the part you want a "clip" and set looping for that.  The help files will explain the details.

Unfortunately, the looping stays within Quicktime—if you save the video, it still won't loop outside of Quicktime.  You can also import it into Photos, make it a slideshow project, remove all audio, and have it loop in the photos app, but that's a bit more awkward.